# How to get Value of a variable outside the Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Iam using Html2Canvas.js for converting a div into canvas

```
var canvasimage=""; 
html2canvas($("#dvorder"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        $('#imgDemo').append(canvas);
        $('#imgDemo canvas').attr('id', 'Billcan');                   
        canvasimage = document.getElementById('Billcan').toDataURL("image/png");                   
    }
});
```

How to get the value of variable canvasimage outside the html2Canvas
please refer to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

Comment: you either need a global variable or instead of defining the method within click handler, just pass an existing function to onrendered event that has access to variables you want to change